# How to make a vertical line in grid in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see the grid below is the what bootstrap website shows in their website but when you use the code there is no vertical line in the middle.

I found some answer related to this but those were from the last version of bootstrap so asking again.

```
<div class="row">   
<div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>   
<div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div> 
</div>
```

[image: Bootstrap grid]

Comment: In Bootstrap's documentation they did this by adding a `border: 1px solid #ddd` to all the `col-*` classes. But what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

They are doing this by adding borders, there are several options of how you can do this.

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-xs-6 bordered">.col-xs-6</div>   
    <div class="col-xs-6 bordered">.col-xs-6</div> 
</div>
```

In your style sheet:

```
.bordered {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

You can plan around with the border (border-right, border-left, etc..) to get it how you like it.

Here is a CodePen with a border around everything and one with just a border down the middle

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPvLRe)

Comment: His second div needs to be fixed.